# Difference between two datetime with Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 4 columns : `Date1, Time1, Date2, Time2`.

My objective is to know the time difference between two datetime in format `hh:mm:ss`.

Some examples :

```
Date1       | Time1    | Date2      | Time2    | ExpectedResult
12/11/2019  | 12:00:00 | 16/11/2019 | 15:00:00 | 99:00:00
10/11/2019  | 11:10:00 | 10/11/2019 | 12:09:15 | 00:59:15
...
```

With VBA there is no problem. However, is it possible to do it wihtout VBA but with a formula? Thank you.

**Format**

`Date1` and `Date2` have the format : `*14/03/2012`

`Time1`, `Time2` and `ExpectedResult` have the format : `hh:mm:ss`

**Already tried**

```
=(Date2+Time2)-(Date1+Time1)
```

But the result is `03:00:00`. Days are not present.

Comment: Are you sure that you have correct formats?

Comment: I updated my question with formats used.

Comment: This seems like a formatting issue. When I try the formula you gave, I get 4.13 (days) then I simply multiply it with 24 and get 99.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad), use a custom format: `[h]:mm;@`. In your case you want `[hh]:mm:ss;@`

[image]